# Wordpress rewrite not working with different post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a plugin in which i am detecting the selected custom field. If the user has selected boy in custom field then the url tends to be www.example.com/boys/shirts if the user selects girls then the url tends to be www.example.com/girls/top. The problem is the wordpress rewite is working only for one case everytime. I purge the settings for permalinks after changing the option and saving the post. the url with

```
    if($model_type=="boys") {
            $labels = array(
                'name'                => _x( 'Boys', 'Post Type General Name', $txtdomain ),
                'singular_name'       => _x( 'Boy', 'Post Type Singular Name', $txtdomain ),
                'menu_name'           => __( 'Models', $txtdomain ),
                'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Model', $txtdomain ),
                'all_items'           => __( 'All Models', $txtdomain ),
                'view_item'           => __( 'View Model', $txtdomain ),
                'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Model', $txtdomain ),
                'add_new'             => __( 'New Model', $txtdomain ),
                'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Model', $txtdomain ),
                'update_item'         => __( 'Update Model', $txtdomain ),
                'search_items'        => __( 'Search models', $txtdomain ),
                'not_found'           => __( 'No models found', $txtdomain ),
                'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No models found in Trash', $txtdomain ),
            );

            $this->args = array(
                'description'           => __( 'Models-boys', $txtdomain ),
                'labels'                => $labels,
                'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
                'hierarchical'          => false,
                'public'                => true,
                'show_ui'               => true,
                'show_in_menu'          => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
                'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
                'menu_icon'             => trailingslashit( $uri ) . 'images/model-icon.png',
                'can_export'            => true,
                'has_archive'           => true,
                'exclude_from_search'   => false,
                'publicly_queryable'    => true,
                'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'boys' )
            );
    } else {
            $labels = array(
                'name'                => _x( 'Girls', 'Post Type General Name', $txtdomain ),
                'singular_name'       => _x( 'Girl', 'Post Type Singular Name', $txtdomain ),
                'menu_name'           => __( 'Models', $txtdomain ),
                'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Model', $txtdomain ),
                'all_items'           => __( 'All Models', $txtdomain ),
                'view_item'           => __( 'View Model', $txtdomain ),
                'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Model', $txtdomain ),
                'add_new'             => __( 'New Model', $txtdomain ),
                'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Model', $txtdomain ),
                'update_item'         => __( 'Update Model', $txtdomain ),
                'search_items'        => __( 'Search models', $txtdomain ),
                'not_found'           => __( 'No models found', $txtdomain ),
                'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No models found in Trash', $txtdomain ),
            );

            $this->args = array(
                'description'           => __( 'Models-mens', $txtdomain ),
                'labels'                => $labels,
                'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
                'hierarchical'          => false,
                'public'                => true,
                'show_ui'               => true,
                'show_in_menu'          => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
                'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
                'menu_icon'             => trailingslashit( $uri ) . 'images/model-icon.png',
                'can_export'            => true,
                'has_archive'           => true,
                'exclude_from_search'   => false,
                'publicly_queryable'    => true,
                'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'girls' )
            );
    }
```

The Girls is working and open the single.php but boys open the not found page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that is possible to have a double structure like this,
but you can try to add this in your code:

```
flush_rewrite_rules( false );
```

both in `if` block and in `else` block at the end.

'Cause you must force the change of structure at the occurrence.

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

Comment: Well this actually seems to work for me. Seems great. But does it changes htaccess again and again

Comment: I have custom codes in htaccess. Will that get erased whenever this is called ?

Comment: I don't know, and I can't tell you the effects on `.htaccess`. I suggest you to get a copy of `.htaccess` and try. Normally the other parameters should remain intact or at least would be rewritten in the same manner automatically.

Comment: I see in codex.wordpress.org. Parameters: (boolean) (optional) Whether to update .htaccess (hard flush) or just update rewrite_rules transient (soft flush). Default: true (hard flush). Try `flush_rewrite_rules( false );`

Comment: But i also read that using this function in every page reload is not recommended. It will flush even if i use soft on every page load. Will that be good ? Your solution works but i am concerned

Comment: Try `flush_rewrite_rules( false );` It is not recommended unless necessary. In your case is the only solution (that I know).

Comment: Yups trying that and it works. The major concern is that its written everywhere that this should not be done in every page reload. Does flush_rewrite_rules( false ) is safe to use ?

Comment: It's less invasive then `flush_rewrite_rules( true );` this is sure.

Comment: So i can use it for sure with page loads ? Or is there any other solution ? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: In any case is a function that many plugins of wordpress use, and it's necessary and required when you write code that modify permalink structure.

Comment: The only things you can try is to remove the function from the `else` block and leave him alone in the `if` block so as to call it one less time. ButI'm not sure that it works anyway. 'Cause when you switch from boys to girls no one tell the system that links are changed. Tell my if works.

Comment: emm i should check that. 5mins

Comment: This is a good solution but then mens case permalinks stops working. What i did is i put another if condition. So now its not refreshing rules on any other pages or post which does not have boys or girls slug. Will this be all?

Comment: It's a good thing! So it refresh only if there is a `boys` or `girls` slug in permalinks, but in any case you need to call refresh in `if` and `else` block. I think this is all! :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103245/discussion-between-yeti82-and-user1001176).